# BreadCrumb doesn't show the correct url of taxonomies

Tags: orchardcms, taxonomy, breadcrumbs

In orchard CMS I have a taxonomies menu.I have added a alias breadcrumb menu.When I chose a taxonomy menu,the alias is correct.(Home->product->adidas->shoes)
but when I click one of shoes post,the url is changed to(Home->shoes1).
How can I fixed it to (Home->product->adidas->shoes->shoes1)?

Answer (score 0):

I think u need to edit the `content type` of shoe and modify the Autoroute `content part` setting and give it a new default pattern url that matches your sample `(Home->product->adidas->shoes)`